# Algebra question resubmited

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello I have a quick algebra question.

If I have the following expression

$\large \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, and I multiply the numerator and the denominator by $(x^2+1)$.

Is there any way I can get $x^4+x^2−1$?

The reason I am asking this is because on a problem I did this expression came up and it confused I will post the link.

Comment: This is the question where the expression occurs http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260117/solving-a-trig-equation-with-inverse

Comment: Your previous question was closed. This is a literal copy. Why did you think it wouldn't get closed this time?

Comment: Previous closed question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263482/algebra-question-involving-fraction

Comment: @akkkk Maybe because, now, the question is well-phrased...

Comment: @DavidMitra: only because of the later edits by Crete and amWhy after my comment, and the question is still not clear to me.

Comment: In the other question you like you have an equation: $x^2 = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$. Clearing the denominator, you have $x^4 + x^2 = 1$ which you just rewrite as $x^4 + x^2 - 1 = 0$...

Comment: @akkkk If you check the edit history, you'll note that only formatting and grammatical changes were made. The original post was indeed unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially repeating Tyler Bailey's comment, in the answer to the linked question you faced solving $$x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

Squaring both sides, noting this might introduce spurious solutions, gave 
$$x^2=\dfrac{1}{{x^2+1}}.$$

Multiplying both sides by $x^2+1$ (not numerator and denominator), which might lead to spurious solutions of the form $x=\pm i$ but in fact does not here, gave $$x^4 +x^2 =1.$$

Subtracting $1$ from both sides gave $$x^4 +x^2 -1 = 0.$$

This is about changes to an equation not an expression.

Comment: Oh I see now gracias.